# Graceful way to rsync millions of files between two local folders

Tags: ubuntu, backup, performance, command-line-interface, rsync

I want to `rsync` a folder with millions of files from a local directory to another, on a daily basis. The files themselves change very rarely.

I want to reduce the impact on the running server, e.g. CPU time or I/O, so I am using the command below

```
nice -n19 ionice -c3 rsync -ac --delete /foo /backup/
```

However, I found that it still causes a lot of CPU spikes and high I/O consumption during the execution of `rsync` command.

Is there any better way to complete my goal?

Comment: Do you actually need the files themselves there, or can you leverage symlinks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need to compare checksums rather that either just the m date or even just the size of the file?

When you use -c

```
-c, --checksum              skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size
```

That means you need to read the entire contents of every file on both file systems. If you turn this off and use the mod-time and size, you only need to stat the directory. I don't think the bwlimit option will help much in this case, since it controls the rate between rsync processes, not the rate at which does I/O on the files to determine the checksum.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using rsync's --bwlimit to limit the bandwith consumed by rsync during the copy operation.

For example, I do something like this to sync video from my security cameras offsite without clobbering my Internet connection too much:

```
rsync -avv --bwlimit=180 --delete --exclude '*.jpg'  remote.server.com:/stuff
```

--Scott

Comment: This only limits bandwidth on a per-file basis, so it works well with large files. With millions of small files, though, there will be very little effect.